# Медиазапросы в CSS и HTML

Tags: css3, html5

Когда задаю свойства для @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) то эти свойства передаются и для @media screen and (min-width: 2000px). Нельзя ли задавать Определенный интервал?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй ограничить верхнее значение. Например вот так:

```
@media  screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px){
    body { line-height: 1.4 }
}
```

[документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: спасибо огромное))